# filebeat version 7.13.1 not working with aws elasticserach 7.4

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, amazon-elasticsearch

Can someone help me with the below error?

#filebeat test output -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml

```
talk to server... ERROR Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: could not connect to a compatible version of Elasticsearch: unauthorized access, could not connect to the xpack endpoint, verify your credentials
```

OS version:

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
> Release:        18.04
> Codename:       bionic

Elasticsearch version:

> 7.4

FileBeat version:

> filebeat version 7.13.1 (amd64), libbeat 7.13.1 [2d80f6e99f41b65a270d61706fa98d13cfbda18d built 2021-05-28 16:38:20 +0000 UTC]

I am using Elasticsearch Service from AWS and using OSS version of filebeat. It was working fine with filebeat version 7.12.1. When the version got upgraded we are facing this issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [breaking change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/breaking-changes-7.13.html#breaking-changes-7.13) in version 7.13.

From version 7.13+ Filebeat will only work with the Elasticsearch distribution from Elastic as it will now check the license, at least at the moment.

It was caused by this change in [the code](https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/25351), and there is an open [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/26305) to revert the old behavior.

But at the moment if you are not using the Elasticsearch with Elastic license you can't use any beat from version 7.13+, you will need to revert the version.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info. I tried reverting to my old version 7.12.1 but unable to install that version.
Getting this error
"E: The repository 'https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/oss-7.12.1/apt stable Release' does not have a Release file."
Do we have any way to revert or the only option to go with Elastic license. If so how can I get Elastic License?

Comment: You can download the `.deb` file manually and install it, it's available [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/filebeat-oss-7-12-1). The Elastic license is available for the Elastic distribution of Elasticsearch, you are using the AWS fork, which is different. The licensing was changed on version 7.10 and there are no more OSS distributions of the Elastic version of Elasticsearch, you can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing). The beats still have OSS distributions, but some things could break, which is your case.

Comment: Great info!! AWS suggesting to move to opensearch https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-opensearch/ I will go with Elastic distribution.